# Problem with Babel Loader for React and Redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, babeljs

I am new and learning `Redux` for `React` with following an slightly outdated? tutorial.

This is the `index.js` file that is supposed to combine our reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux/src';
import posts from './posts';
import comments from './comments';
  
const rootReducer = combineReducers({posts, comments, routing: routerReducer});

export default rootReducer;
```

But the error I get is this:

```
Module parse failed: C:\MyOwnGitHub\REDUX\node_modules\react-router-redux\src\index.js Unexpected token (1:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:7)
```

So I Googled the error and some SO posts came up. People were saying it has to do with some `.babelrc` file and updating some `webpack` stuff related to babel loader. But I don't know those things.

I did try to copy as much as I understood from their edit suggestions but this isn't still working. I get the same error.  Can someone take a look at my settings and see what should I do to fix it?

I know you need to look at some `package.json` and other config files and they are pretty large to copy paste here so if it is OK I am just going to post the GitHub link here so you can look around:

https://github.com/BlakeAghili/ReduxReactIG

Comment: React-router-redux is not maintained for quite some time. Please try to use connected-react-router instead. https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router

Comment: Oh wow so the course I was following is pretty old.  OK thanks. I won't just follow that course and pick something newer to step through.